# KeyVault architecture - only user can access their own data

Tags: azure-keyvault

I have a very simple requirement:
Every user in our ad has several api keys, specific to his own user. I want to safely store them into a keyvault but I have the requirement that only the user the key belongs to can access (CRUD) these keys. So basically i want a bucket for every user where only the user itself has permissions to access this bucket.
Is this possible to achieve with a keyvault. because as far as i understand it i can only assign key vault permissions on key vault level, so if i give a user the permissions to access he can read and modify all other keys in this key vault. All users are available in an Azure AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible. For azure keyvault, we could just manage it in Management plane and Data plane, [see Secure access to a key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault). We could not manage the access policy for a specific key in the keyvault.

> because as far as i understand it i can only assign key vault permissions on key vault level, so if i give a user the permissions to access he can read and modify all other keys in this key vault.

Your understanding is right. The workaround is to use different keyvault for different users. Make sure they just have the role in their own keyvault `Access control (IAM)`, not in the IAM of subscription. Then they will be able to access their own keyvault, at last, don't forget to add themselves to the `Access policies` in the keyvault.

Comment: Thank you very much. that's a pitty. i can't help myself but i have the feeling that i want to store secure information for one AD user and only accessible for this single user does not seem to be such a weird requirement, but i can't find anything. Thank you very much.

Comment: FYI as you probably know it is possible now. Curious if you have any thoughts on my answer below or have found any way around the blemishes (esp. the 3rd).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now, sort of, using [Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli), but there are a few blemishes on this approach that I'm still trying to iron out (which is how I found this older question).

- Maybe obvious, but your users have to be using your application through AAD single-sign on (Oauth2, etc.) with impersonation/delegation and the application will need permission to access key vaults generally.
- Each user will need their own role assignment. Azure subscriptions are limited to 4000 (2000 for government) role assignments. So this could severely limit scalability. One way I see around this is to orgnaize users into sub-groups/enterprises and dedicate an entire Azure subscription + Keyvault - all on the same tenant - to each enterprise. Your application will have to track which user is in which subscription/vault so you don't run out of RBAC assignments.
- The worst part IMO is administration. While it is possible to give a user the "Key Vault Secrets Reader" role on just one secret, in order to grant that role in the first place the grantor has to be able to make role assignments on the whole vault. Even if you don't give that person the ability to read secrets, they can give it to themselves if they are determined enough. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to design an admin role which could create a secret that another user can see without having the add/edit role assignments permission on the entire vault. If you gave your application itself this ability, without delegation, that rather defeats the entire purpose of doing this. So instead you would need to live with the fact that any person with the power to add a new user to your application would have power over the entire vault.

In my opinion this is still worth doing because notwithstanding the warts, it still provides greater protection than if the application had unfettered access to the entire vault. To read the data, the attacker would need to compromise both the backend infrastructure AND an admin user's AAD credentials. Either should be very difficult; both - if there is proper separation of roles - should be neigh near impossible.

That said, I find the fact that it is not possible to entrust a true secret to a single AAD user - and only that user - is a glaring omission from AAD and apparently all SSO systems as far as I can tell. On-prem AD has the Windows Data Protection API which does this. AAD should have something similar.